# JSON Query Not returning Value in Ansible playbook

Tags: json, filter, ansible, json-query

Using Ansible, I have a large JSON file that I need to extra a few values from.  A simplified version is here, but shows the basic structure:

```
{
   "metadata": { "version": "1.2.3.4" },
   "operations": [
      {
         "resourceType": "type1",
         "items": 
         [
            { "sometag1": "someval1" },
            { "sometag2": "someval2" }
         ]
      },
      {
         "resourceType": "/certificates/ca",
         "items": 
         [
            { 
               "fileData": "EncryptedCertFile1",
               "id": "trustedCerts_cert1"
            },
            { 
               "fileData": "EncryptedCertFile2",
               "id": "trustedCerts_cert2"
            },
            { 
               "fileData": "EncryptedCertFile3",
               "id": "trustedCerts_cert3"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

These are the two tasks I'm using to get the value:

```
- name: Get Source JSON Data
          set_fact:
            jsonExp: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/{{ src_file_name }}') | from_json }}"

- name: Get Cert Info
  set_fact:
    cert_data: "{{ jsonExp | json_query(jquery) }}"
  vars:
    jquery: "operations[?resourceType=='/certificates/ca'].items[?id=='trustedCerts_cert2')]"
```

But I get returned an empty json array.  I've gone level by level and I can get all the way down to the items array with this query string:

```
operations[?resourceType=='/certificates/ca'].items[*]
```

I can even get a list of the specific labes:

```
operations[?resourceType=='/certificates/ca'].items[*].id
```

or

```
operations[?resourceType=='/certificates/ca'].items[*].fileData
```

I can also target a specific item using the index array:

```
operations[?resourceType=='/certificates/ca'].items[1]
```

But I can't seem to get a query to work to get a specific item by filtering on the "id" entry.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! [This site](https://jmespath.org/) is a great tool for figuring out tricky queries like this(at least tricky for me).  Once I got to the items part of the query, I needed to pipe that into a second query:

```
operations[?resourceType=='/certificates/ca'].items[] | [?Id=='trustedCerts_cert2'].fileData
```

Comment: "this site" is actually the official `jmespath` documentation, the query language used by `json_query`

Answer (score 0):

Following your auto answer, `json_query` is indeed very powerful for complex queries.

Meanwhile, it is not part of core ansible hence requires to install an extra collection and python lib. Moreover there have been (and there are still IMO) some concerns around jmespath maintenance. You can find a recap of some example issues [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66496) and AFAIK the `to_json | from_json` trick needed for some complex queries is still needed (although you are not concerned here).

All of the above to explain that, even if I am still a big `json_query` fan, I tend to limit its use nowadays to situation where core ansible cannot cope with the job at all. It's definitely not the case in your example.

Using your exact same example file I saved in `/tmp/somedata.json`, the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Search for elements
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    src_file_name: somedata.json
    json_exp: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/' ~ src_file_name) | from_json }}"
    search_type: "/certificates/ca"
    search_id: "trustedCerts_cert2"
    cert_list: >-
      {{
        json_exp.operations
        | selectattr('resourceType', '==', search_type)
        | map(attribute='items')
        | flatten
        | selectattr('id', '==', search_id)
        | map(attribute='fileData')
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: "Show Cert Info"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ cert_list }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [Search for elements] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Show Cert Info] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "EncryptedCertFile2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```